# C Method for Diffraction grating

Tags: optics, mathematical-physics, diffraction

Alright, so I am trying to find the efficiencies of a coated diffraction grating through the method in [this paper](http://www.mcgrating.com/references/ref02.pdf).  This is through a change of coordinate system.  So I went through and derived all of the equations up until equation 26.

I get lost at the Outgoing wave condition.  I understand what he is doing, I just get confused as to how both equations 26 and 28 are true.  Additionally, I do not see how he can solve equation 28.  I am trying to do so in MatLab, and I only get errors saying that there are dimension mismatches.

I would really appreciate any help!  Thanks

Comment: I won't have time to look at the paper until tomorrow, but if matlab is giving you a dimension mismatch, you're having a problem with your code, not your math.

Comment: Dear yankeefan11 Do you understand the difference between Eqs (26) and (28) is that now I _believe_ (not altogether sure) the authors have redefined the $\mathbf{b}_j$ so that now the evanescent field components are kept out of these vectors? If you haven't yet noticed this, then this observation might help you. The authors haven't been clear on this point - for clarity they should write an equation relating new and former $\mathbf{b}_j$. As for solvability, I'm guessing that the evanescent components are going to be dropped altogether when it comes to farfield boundary conditions.